# How to calculate $*dx^i$ on an oriented Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a $d$ dimensional oriented Riemannian manifold, $(x^i)$ an oriented local chart, then we can define a star operator $*:\Omega^p(M)\to\Omega^{d-p}(M)$ by looking at orthonormal frames. But how can we calculate $*dx^i$? Can it be expressed as a function of $g^{jk}$ and $dx^1\wedge\cdots\wedge\widehat{dx^j}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^d$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it can.

The Hodge star operator is characterized by$$\alpha\wedge*\beta=\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle\mathrm{vol},$$where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are differential forms of the same degree. So, for $*dx^i$ you have $$dx^j\wedge* dx^i=g^{ij}\mathrm{vol},\quad j=1,\ldots,n.$$Letting $\omega_{ij}$ denote the coefficient of $dx^1\wedge\ldots\widehat{dx^j}\ldots\wedge dx^n$, the above equality means that (up to sign! But I'm not gonna go into signs...) $$\omega_{ij}dx^1\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^n=g^{ij}\mathrm{vol}=g^{ij}\sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}dx^1\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^n,$$and you have what you need.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I've been having a huge mental block about this for a week for some reason.

Comment: Similarly, is it difficult to calculate $$\operatorname{\ast}(\mathrm{d}x^1\wedge\cdots\wedge\widehat{\mathrm{d}x^i}\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathrm{d}x^d)?$$

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine You know that $**=(-1)^{\mathrm{sign}$. In other words, $*$ is the inverse of itself up to sign. So you just need to take the inverse of the expression in my answer.